# DHTML Calendar Widget : calender open with specified date

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, calendar, dhtml

I am using [calender dhtml widget](http://www.dni.ru/js/doc/html/reference.html) in my project. I want calendar to be open on the date that I have specified but not on the end date.

Example :
Today is 06/22/2015.

I want when I click on calendar it should open with 04/20/2015.

Please let me know which API I should call. Please advice.

Comment: why are you using a 10 year old widget.  Consider jquery.ui

Comment: this is an old code and sure who has written it. if possible please let me know by using dhtm calendar widget only